# Test Class throwing error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature"

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Title says it all. I'm getting this error when trying to test a custom method. I checked to make sure that there weren't multiple classes with the same name as suggested by many other SE threads. I also made sure I wasn't leaving out or trying to pass parameters incorrectly. Here's my code; it's incredibly straightforward.

Custom Class:

```
public class BorrowerSurveyCon{

    Contact c = new Contact();

    private BorrowerSurvey__c borrSurr;

    public BorrowerSurveyCon(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        this.borrSurr = (BorrowerSurvey__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public pageReference SaveandClose()
    {
        try
        {
            string survName = 'Survey ';
            survName += datetime.now();

            Contact conList = [select NMLS__c from Contact where NMLS__c = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('nmls') limit 1];

            c = conList;

            this.borrSurr.LO_Name__c = c.Id;
            this.borrSurr.Name = survName;
            upsert this.borrSurr;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error creating/updating record'));
        }
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/a06?fcf=00Bg0000001FdE6');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);

        return pageRef;
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class BorrowerSurveyConTest {
    static testMethod void testSaveAndClose() {
        pageReference r = BorrowerSurveyCon.SaveandClose();
    }
}
```

On the test class, it's saying that BorrowerSurveyCon.SaveandClose does not exist, despite the Console having auto-completed that method call for me. Any idea why SF can't seem to find my BorrowerSurveyCon class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a difference between an instance method and a static method.
Static methods can be called without instantiation of the class containing it.

For your case, your method is not static. So you have to instantiate your class before calling it:

```
BorrowerSurvey__c borrower = new BorrowerSurvey__c();
... // you have to set the fields of borrower
BorrowerSurveyCon controller = new BorrowerSurveyCon(borrower);
pageReference r = controller.SaveandClose();
```

**NOTE**

If you want more information about extensions testing, here's the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm).