# Method X does not exist in the apex class with Id Y or Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I am trying to push my code to production, but I always get 58% coverage which I am not sure sure why since I am testing most of my classes ...
Anyway I added one test to improve my coverage but I am getting Method getPropertiestable does not exist in the apex class with Id :01p260000040zai

I am not sure why ... Could you please explain me what is the issue and how to improve by coverage ?

here is my code:
Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class PicklistHelper {
    public PicklistHelper() {

    }
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String,String> getRegion(){
        Map<String,String> regionMap = new Map<String,String>();
        for(Region__c regionObj:[select id,name from Region__c ]){
            regionMap.put(regionObj.Id,regionObj.Name);
        }
        return regionMap;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String,String> getCountry(string RegionId){
        Map<String,String> CountryMap = new Map<String,String>();
        for(Country__c countryObj:[select id,name from Country__c where Region__c = :RegionId]){
            CountryMap.put(countryObj.Id,countryObj.Name);
        }
        return CountryMap;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String,String> getMarket(string CountryId){
        Map<String,String> MarketMap = new Map<String,String>();
        for(Market__c marketObj:[select id, name from Market__c  where country_link__c = :CountryId]){
            MarketMap.put(marketObj.Id,marketObj.Name);
        }
        return MarketMap;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String,String> propertiesFromMarket(string MarketId){
        Map<String,String> MarketMap = new Map<String,String>();
        for(Lead propObj:[select id, Name, Status, LeadSource from Lead where Market__c = :MarketId]){
            MarketMap.put(propObj.Id, propObj.Name);
            MarketMap.put('Status', propObj.Status);
        }
        return MarketMap;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Lead> propertiesFromMarketBis(Integer countryCheckBox, string MarketId, string selectedCountry){
        if(countryCheckBox == 1){
            return [select Id, Name, Status, LeadSource, Number_of_Keys__c, Neighbourhood__c from Lead where Market__c = :MarketId];
        } else{
            return [select Id, Name, Status, LeadSource, Number_of_Keys__c, Neighbourhood__c from Lead where Market__r.country_link__c = :selectedCountry];
        }
             
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Opportunity> OpportunitiesFromMarket(string MarketId, Integer countryCheckBox, string selectedCountry){
        if(countryCheckBox == 1){
            return [select Id, Name, StageName, NextStep, CloseDate, Owner.Name from Opportunity where Market__c = :MarketId];
        } else {
            return [select Id, Name, StageName, NextStep, CloseDate, Owner.Name from Opportunity where Market__r.country_link__c = :selectedCountry];
        }
        
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Lead> propertiesFromCountry(string CountryId){
        return [select Id, Name, Status, LeadSource, Number_of_Keys__c, Neighbourhood__c from Lead where Market__r.country_link__c = :CountryId];
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Lead> LWCtable(string MarketId){
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Number_of_Keys__c, X1st_Contact__c, X2nd_Contact__c, X3rd_Contact__c, X4th_Contact__c , Status  
                FROM Lead 
                WHERE Market__c = :MarketId 
                AND Status = 'Qualified, Not Contacted'];
    }
    
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void saveOutreachProperty(List<Lead> records){
        if(records != null){
            for(Lead record: records) {
                Id testId = record.Id;
                Lead prop = [SELECT Id, Name, Number_of_Keys__c, X1st_Contact__c, X2nd_Contact__c, X3rd_Contact__c, X4th_Contact__c , Status
                              FROM lead
                              WHERE Id = :testId
                             ];
                prop.LastName = record.name;
                prop.Number_of_Keys__c = record.Number_of_Keys__c;
                prop.X1st_Contact__c = record.X1st_Contact__c;
                prop.X2nd_Contact__c = record.X2nd_Contact__c;
                prop.X3rd_Contact__c = record.X3rd_Contact__c;
                prop.X4th_Contact__c = record.X4th_Contact__c;
                update prop;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Apex test:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
public class picklisthelperTest {
     @testSetup
    static void insertFileds() { 
        Region__c Region = new Region__c (
            Name = 'Europe'
        );
        insert Region;

        country__c Country = new country__c (
            Name = 'UK',
            Region__c = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Region__c WHERE Name = 'Europe' ]
        );
        insert Country;
        
        Market__c Market = new Market__C (
            Name = 'Cornwell',
            country__c = [SELECT Id, Name FROM country__c WHERE Name = 'UK' ]
        );
        insert Market;

        Lead P = new Lead ( 
            Title = 'Property 1',
            LastName = 'Preperty 1 LN',
            LeadSource = 'Broker',
            Status = 'Qualified, Not Contacted',
            Number_of_Keys__c = 50, 
            X1st_Contact__c = 'contact 1', 
            X2nd_Contact__c = 'contact 2', 
            X3rd_Contact__c = 'contact 3', 
            X4th_Contact__c = 'contact 4',
            Market__c = [SELECT Id, Name, Title FROM Lead WHERE Name = 'Cornwell' ]
        );
        insert P;
        
        Lead P2 = new Lead ( 
            Title = 'Property 2',
            LastName = 'Preperty 2 LN',
            LeadSource = 'Broker',
            Status = 'Qualified, Not Contacted',
            Number_of_Keys__c = 60, 
            X1st_Contact__c = 'contact 1', 
            X2nd_Contact__c = 'contact 2', 
            X3rd_Contact__c = 'contact 3', 
            X4th_Contact__c = 'contact 4',
            Market__c = [SELECT Id, Name, Title FROM Lead WHERE Name = 'Cornwell' ]
        );
        insert P2;
        
        Lead P3 = new Lead ( 
            Title = 'Property 3',
            LastName = 'Preperty 3 LN',
            LeadSource = 'Broker',
            Status = 'Qualified, Not Contacted',
            Number_of_Keys__c = 70, 
            X1st_Contact__c = 'contact 1', 
            X2nd_Contact__c = 'contact 2', 
            X3rd_Contact__c = 'contact 3', 
            X4th_Contact__c = 'contact 4',
            Market__c = [SELECT Id, Name, Title FROM Lead WHERE Name = 'Cornwell' ]
        );
        insert P3;
        
        
        

    }
    
    @isTest
    static void getProperties() 
    {
        
        Lead Properties = [SELECT Id, Name, Title
                          FROM Lead
                          LIMIT 1];
        
        Market__c Market = [SELECT Id, Name
                           FROM Market__c
                           LIMIT 1];
        
        Region__c Region = [SELECT Id, Name 
                           FROM Region__c
                           LIMIT 1];
        
        country__c Country = [SELECT Id, Name 
                           FROM country__c
                           LIMIT 1];
        
        Integer countryCheckbox = 1;
        
        System.Test.startTest();
        PicklistHelper.getRegion(); 
        PicklistHelper.getCountry(Region.id); //regionID
        PicklistHelper.getMarket(Country.id); //countryID
        PicklistHelper.propertiesFromMarket(Market.id); //marketID
        PicklistHelper.propertiesFromMarketBis(countryCheckbox, Market.id, Country.id); // countryCheckBox, MarketId, selectedCountry
        PicklistHelper.OpportunitiesFromMarket(Market.id, countryCheckbox, Country.id); // MarketId, countryCheckBox, selectedCountry
        PicklistHelper.propertiesFromCountry(Country.id); // selectedCountry
        PicklistHelper.LWCtable(Market.id); 
        
        System.Test.stopTest();     
    }

    @isTest
    static void getPropertiestable() 
    {
        Lead Properties = [SELECT Id, Name, Title, Status
                          FROM Lead
                          ];
        
        Market__c Market = [SELECT Id, Name
                          FROM Market__c
                          LIMIT 1];

        System.Test.startTest();
        PicklistHelper.LWCtable(Market.Id); 
        System.Test.stopTest();
        
    }
    
}
```

thx you

Comment: Is the error occurring in the sandbox or during deployment in production?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/160300/81648) solve this problem for you? | As an aside, just because you have tests that pass does not automatically mean acceptable code coverage. And just because you have 100% code coverage does not mean that you are adequately testing. Both (testing and code coverage) occur at the same time, but there is more of a correlation than a causation between the two (if that makes sense).However if you are diligently, actually, thoroughly testing your classes you *should* get a high code coverage percentage.

Comment: Yes it does ! I brought my code coverage to 98%